# LINQ group by select with collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable e.g.

```
ID  Agent  Date
1   A1    2016-02-19
2   A1    2016-02-20
3   A2    2016-02-19
4   A3    2016-02-20
```

i want to group these records by Date and return the ID and Agent is list like:

```
Date:2016-02-19 ,{(1,A1),(3,A2)}
Date:2016-02-20 ,{(2,A1),(4,A3)}
```

A collection object of ID and Agent Group by Date.
Please suggect how to achieve it using LINQ.

Comment: Can you please show your code and tell what is wrong with it. Are you using LINQ to DataSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that something like the below would do that you want.

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                      .GroupBy(row=>row.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                      .Select(gr=>new 
                      {
                          Date = gr.Key,
                          Agents = gr.Select(x => new 
                          {
                              Id = x.Field<int>("ID"),
                              Agent = x.Field<string>("Agent")
                          })
                      });
```

**Update**

If you need for each date the agents to be a comma separated list of the agents,
like this `{(2,A1),(4,A3)}`, you could try the following approach.

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                          .GroupBy(row=>row.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                          .Select(gr=>new 
                          {
                              Date = gr.Key,
                              Agents = "{"+ string.Join(",", 
                                       gr.Select(x => new 
                              string.Format("({0},{1})", 
                                  x.Field<int>("ID"), 
                                  x.Field<string>("Agent"))+"}"
                              })
                          });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser. I got the result but having new problem.How can i get list of agents (, separated) from Agents Object later in my code)

Comment: @Devendra You are welcome. Should this be a string of all the agent in a specific date?

Comment: Yes..One way is .Select(gr=>new 
                      {
                          Date = gr.Key,
arrAgents=String.Join(",", gr.Select(z => z.Field<string>("Agent"))),
                          Agents = gr.Select(x => new 
                          {
                              Id = x.Field<int>("ID"),
                              Agent = x.Field<string>("Agent")
                          })
                      });

Comment: Just a minute, this would create a sequence of anonymous objects with two properties, one the date and the other the agents. The agents would be another sequence with two properties, Id and Agent. So this is not a list of agents separated with comma.

Comment: In order to understand what you want, please specify an exact output format given the input you have. Thank you

Comment: foreach (var res in result)
                        {
                            var lstAgents = res.Agents;
now i want here agent (,separated) from lstAgents.

Comment: Do you want Agents to be like this {(2,A1),(4,A3)}?

Comment: how can i pass "Agents" collection as argument to other method and what will be the type of this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example class:

```
public class Log
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Agent { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Log(int id, string agent, DateTime date)
    {
        ID = id;
        Agent = agent;
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

And here the LINQ statement with some test data:

```
List<Log> list = new List<Log>()
{
    new Log(1, "A", new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)),
    new Log(2, "B", new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)),
    new Log(3, "C", new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)),
    new Log(4, "A", new DateTime(2016, 01, 02, 0, 0, 0)),
    new Log(5, "A", new DateTime(2016, 01, 03, 0, 0, 0))
};

var result = from entry in list
             group entry by entry.Date
             into g
             select g;
```

This will group all your data into groups with a *Key* based on `Log.Date`, where each group consits of multiple entries, each with an `ID`, `Agent` and `Date` property.

Here some example code how to access `result`:

```
result.ToList().ForEach(group =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key); // The date
    group.ToList().ForEach(entry => Console.WriteLine(entry.ID + " - " + entry.Agent)); // Print out each entry per group
});
```